# Can you cast a WebElement to a WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to use a WebElement as a root to find elements from instead of the driver. I know this is possible since the WebElement and WebDriver both extends the SearchContext class. But I want to be able to have a search that looks like this.

```
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver driver = chromeDriver;

// Set a new search root
public void setSearchRoot(){
    if(i want a element as a root){
      this.driver = (WebDriver)this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
    }else{
      this.driver = chromeDriver;
    }
}

//find a element
public void findMyElement(){
   this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
}
```

instead of something like this

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver rootElement = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));

//find a element
public void findMyElement(){
   if(i want a element as a root){         
     this.rootElement.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
   }else{
     this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
   }
}
```

It might look a bit messy but basically I want to be able to set a WebElement as a starting point instead of a WebDriver without having to do a if statement or have two different methods whenever I want to get a element. Because sometimes I want to use the WebDriver as a root and sometimes a Webelement and this without having to change anything with the get code. is it possible somehow? And yes I am aware that this might not be best practice, just wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

**using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;**

if element is a type of **ISearchContext** or **IWebElement**

then this cast worked for me

**var driver = ((IWrapsDriver)element).WrappedDriver;**

Answer (score 1):

No, `WebElement` and `WebDriver` are not descendants of each other.

If your `IWebElement` happens to be a `RemoteWebElement`, then you can get the `IWebDriver` with

```
var remoteElement = (RemoteWebElement)element;
var webDriver = remoteElement.WrappedDriver;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use the "root" to find elements under it and not to do other WebDriver specific stuff (like navigation or managing options or timeouts) you can use `SearchContext` instead of `WebDriver`.

Your code would look like this:

```
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
SearchContext driver = chromeDriver; // Use SearchContext instead of WebDriver

// Set a new search root
public void setSearchRoot() {
    if(i want a element as a root) {
      this.driver = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH")); // No cast needed
    } else {
      this.driver = chromeDriver;
    }
}

//find a element
public void findMyElement() {
   this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
}
```

I noticed in my own projects that I often had methods expecting a parameter of type `WebDriver` when really it only called `findElements` on it. By changing the type to `SearchContext` my utilities became a lot more flexible.

```
public WebElement findMyElement(SearchContext webDriver) {
    return webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
WebElement customElement = findMyElement(webDriver);
WebElement nestedElement = findMyElement(customElement);
```